# What is the physical mechanism of the topological phase transition driven by temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-insulators, topological-phase

The topological property of topological insulators (TIs) is characterized by the non-trivial topological invariants of their band structures, such as $Z_{2}$ topological invariants. While it's clearly shown in the experiments that when the temperature raise, the system becomes a trivial insulator. My question is how do we understand such phase transition if the non-trivial topological properties all come from the band structure, which is supposed to be independent of temperature? Is there any physical mechanism (picture) for such phase transition?

Comment: As you already mentioned, topological properties all come from the band structure, which really means ground state wavefunction. There is no sharp distinction between topological/trivial insulators at finite temperature. In particular, there is generally no thermal phase transition if the temperature is increased in a topological insulator, unless the topological insulator itself happens to be the result of certain spontaneous symmetry breaking (not the symmetry that protects the phase!).